# On Android 5.0 lollipop maybe due to depricated getRunningTask() method

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

Application is working with in Kitkat version. After lollipop version application is not working properly. I am thinking problem with getRunningTasks() . Could you please give me guidance ,How to overcome this problem.

```
public class StartupServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Log.d("Detector", "Auto Start" + AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).isAutoStart());
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){

        if (AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).isAutoStart()){

            if (AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).isServiceEnabled()){

                context.startService(new Intent(context, DetectorService.class));

            }else{
                AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).saveServiceEnabled(false);

            }
        }
        return;
    }else if (AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).isServiceEnabled()){
         Toast.makeText(context, "App------>6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        context.startService(new Intent(context, DetectorService.class));
    }
}
}
```

DetectorService

```
public class DetectorService extends Service {
//public static final String ACTION_DETECTOR_SERVICE = "com.gueei.detector.service";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private static final Class<?>[] mStartForegroundSignature = new Class[] {
    int.class, Notification.class};
private static final Class<?>[] mStopForegroundSignature = new Class[] {
    boolean.class};

private NotificationManager mNM;
private Method mStartForeground;
private Method mStopForeground;
private Object[] mStartForegroundArgs = new Object[2];
private Object[] mStopForegroundArgs = new Object[1];

/**
 * This is a wrapper around the new startForeground method, using the older
 * APIs if it is not available.
 */
void startForegroundCompat(int id, Notification notification) {
    // If we have the new startForeground API, then use it.
    if (mStartForeground != null) {
        mStartForegroundArgs[0] = Integer.valueOf(id);
        mStartForegroundArgs[1] = notification;
        try {
            mStartForeground.invoke(this, mStartForegroundArgs);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // Should not happen.
            //debug: log.w("Detector", "Unable to invoke startForeground", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // Should not happen.
            //debug: log.w("Detector", "Unable to invoke startForeground", e);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Fall back on the old API.
    stopForeground(true);
    mNM.notify(id, notification);
}

/**
 * This is a wrapper around the new stopForeground method, using the older
 * APIs if it is not available.
 */
void stopForegroundCompat(int id) {
    // If we have the new stopForeground API, then use it.
    if (mStopForeground != null) {
        mStopForegroundArgs[0] = Boolean.TRUE;
        try {
            mStopForeground.invoke(this, mStopForegroundArgs);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // Should not happen.
            //debug: log.w("Detector", "Unable to invoke stopForeground", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // Should not happen.
            //debug: log.w("Detector", "Unable to invoke stopForeground", e);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Fall back on the old API.  Note to cancel BEFORE changing the
    // foreground state, since we could be killed at that point.
    mNM.cancel(id);
    stopForeground(false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    //debug: log.i("Detector","Service.Oncreate");
    initConstant();
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        mStartForeground = getClass().getMethod("startForeground",
                mStartForegroundSignature);
        mStopForeground = getClass().getMethod("stopForeground",
                mStopForegroundSignature);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // Running on an older platform.
        mStartForeground = mStopForeground = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //debug: log.i("Detector","Service.Ondestroy");
    mThread.interrupt();

    // Make sure our notification is gone.
    stopForegroundCompat(R.string.service_running);
}

 // This is the old onStart method that will be called on the pre-2.0
// platform.  On 2.0 or later we override onStartCommand() so this
// method will not be called.
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //debug: log.i("Detector","Service.Onstart");
    handleCommand(intent);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //debug: log.i("Detector","Service.OnStartCommand");
    handleCommand(intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void handleCommand(Intent intent){
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.service_running);

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.statusbar_icon, text,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, AppLockerActivity.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, text,
                   text, contentIntent);

    startForegroundCompat(R.string.service_running, notification);

    startMonitorThread((ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
}

private void startMonitorThread(final ActivityManager am){
    if (mThread!=null)
        mThread.interrupt();

    mThread = new MonitorlogThread(new ActivityStartingHandler(this));
    mThread.start();
}

private static Thread mThread;
private static boolean constantInited = false;
private static Pattern ActivityNamePattern; 
private static String logCatCommand;
private static String ClearlogCatCommand;

private void initConstant() {
    //debug: log.i("Detector","Service.OninitConstant");
    if (constantInited) return;
    String pattern = getResources().getString(R.string.activity_name_pattern);
    //debug: log.d("Detector", "pattern: " + pattern);
    ActivityNamePattern = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    logCatCommand = getResources().getString(R.string.logcat_command);
    ClearlogCatCommand = getResources().getString(R.string.logcat_clear_command);
}
```

MonitorlogThread

```
private class MonitorlogThread extends Thread{

    ActivityStartingListener mListener;
    public MonitorlogThread(ActivityStartingListener listener){
        //debug: log.i("Detector","Monitor//debug: logThread");
        mListener = listener;
    }

    BufferedReader br;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //debug: log.i("Detector","RUN!");

        while(!this.isInterrupted() ){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                ////debug: log.i("Detector","try!");
                //This is the code I use in my service to identify the current foreground application, its really easy:

                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                // The first in the list of RunningTasks is always the foreground task.
                 //Toast.makeText(context, "App------>7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Android", "App------>7----"+am);

                //RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
                RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);

                Log.d("Android", "App------>8----"+foregroundTaskInfo);


                //Toast.makeText(context, "App------>7"+foregroundTaskInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Thats it, then you can easily access details of the foreground app/activity:
                String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
                PackageManager pm = getBaseContext().getPackageManager();
                PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo = null;
                String foregroundTaskAppName = null;
                String foregroundTaskActivityName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName().toString();
                try {
                    foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
                    foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

                    //debug: log.i("Detector",foregroundTaskAppName);
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (mListener!=null){
                    //mListener.onActivityStarting(foregroundAppPackageInfo.packageName,foregroundTaskAppName);
                    mListener.onActivityStarting(foregroundAppPackageInfo.packageName,foregroundTaskActivityName);
                }


              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  // good practice
                  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                  return;
              }
        }

}  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working properly" ? What is the error ?

Comment: Im working on App locker application.If installed this application in KITKAT version device application locking and its working perfect.In marshmallow version device initially its working ,if we restart the device app lock is not working ,applications are open without asking any password. If we just enter application(appLoack app) and exit from app its working perfect.That time its asking password

Comment: Useful informations must be added in the question instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for above 5.0

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         try {
        UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) ctx.getSystemService("usagestats");
        long milliSecs = 60 * 1000;
        Date date = new Date();
        List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, date.getTime() - milliSecs, date.getTime());
        if (queryUsageStats.size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "UsageStats size: " + queryUsageStats.size());
        }
        long recentTime = 0;
        String recentPkg = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < queryUsageStats.size(); i++) {
            UsageStats stats = queryUsageStats.get(i);
            if (i == 0 && !getPackageName().equals(stats.getPackageName())) {
                Log.i(TAG, "PackageName: " + stats.getPackageName() + " " + stats.getLastTimeStamp());
            }
            if (stats.getLastTimeStamp() > recentTime) {
                String recentTime = stats.getLastTimeStamp();
                String recentPkg = stats.getPackageName();
            }
        };
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Its not working.                                                                 
Im working on App locker application.If installed this application in KITKAT version device application locking and its working perfect.In marshmallow version device initially its working ,if we restart the device app lock is not working ,applications are open without asking any password. If we just enter application(appLoack app) and exit from app its working perfect.That time its asking password

Answer (score 0):

Use RunningAppProcessInfo instead of getRunningTasks for SDK versions greater than KitKat.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    ... 
} else {
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay.I have added this code ,but im getting topActivity cannot be resolved or is not a field. String foregroundTaskPackageName = taskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();

Comment: Use  taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

Comment: Not working..Getting same problem.                                                                                 
Im working on App locker application.If installed this application in KITKAT version device application locking and its working perfect.In marshmallow version device initially its working ,if we restart the device app lock is not working ,applications are open without asking any password. If we just enter application(appLock app) and exit from app its working perfect.That time its asking password

Comment: Can you try this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo) am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        String foregroundTaskPackageName = runningAppProcessInfo.pkgList.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        PackageManager pm = getBaseContext().getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo = null;
        String foregroundTaskAppName = null;
        String foregroundTaskActivityName = runningAppProcessInfo.pkgList.getClass().getName();
        try {
            foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
            foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

            //debug: log.i("Detector",foregroundTaskAppName);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } else {
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
        String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
        PackageManager pm = getBaseContext().getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo = null;
        String foregroundTaskAppName = null;
        String foregroundTaskActivityName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName().toString();
        try {
            foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
            foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

            //debug: log.i("Detector",foregroundTaskAppName);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: In this line crash is coming     --->           ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo) am.getRunningAppProcesses();

Comment: 03-30 12:04:59.206 11950 11963 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.yyyy.applocker, PID: 11950
03-30 12:04:59.206 11950 11963 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.yyyy.applocker.DetectorService$MonitorlogThread.run(DetectorService.java:232)

Comment: what is your targetSdkversion and compilesdkversion added?

Comment: add this to manifest<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

Comment: Initially ,I gave this this permission .And my <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />           This code is working in jelly bean.Not working in marshmallow.

Comment: what is the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion?

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="21"

Comment: oh thats the issue.. make target and compiledskd versions as 23.. 23 is the api level of marshmallow. otherwise it will not work on marshmallow. dont forget to change in both your manifest file and build,gradle file

Comment: I have changed target version is 23 and My IDE is Eclipse...Getting another error...The method setLatestEventInfo(DetectorService, CharSequence, CharSequence, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type Notification

Comment: setLatestEventInfo is deprecated do it using NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: setLatestEventInfo error is resoled ...still im getting same error..                      In this line crash is coming ---> ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo) am.getRunningAppProcesses();

Comment: get the permission in security->"apps with usage access" and add permission permission.REAL_GET_TASKS in the manifest. Check if works.